# How to add Angular2 Materials to project and test it?

Tags: angular

I use AngularJS 2 installed following instructions on the official tutorial. How to add easy Angular Materials in project?

And how start to use these materials, for example, **to add an button to HTML** component?

I use Windows command prompt.

```
npm -v // 3.10/10
```

I tried this:

```
npm install - —save @angular2-material/core
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md

Comment: How can I test this then?

Comment: Test what? I don't get what the whole question is about.

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem? What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Comment: I have installed following instructions. Now I try to add button from material in component. How to make this?

Comment: I doubt you followed the official tutorial [https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

As @Günter already pointed, you have to follow this official guide: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/getting-started.md

**Install Angular Material components**

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

**Import the Angular Material NgModule**

```js
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
// other imports 
@NgModule({
  imports: [MaterialModule.forRoot()],
  ...
})
export class PizzaPartyAppModule { }
```

And use a button like this:

```html
<button md-button>Basic Button</button>
<button md-raised-button>Raised Button</button>
```

Here's a demo plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/o077B6uEiiIgkC0S06dd?p=preview